# How to find Jenkins version through CLI command? Is there any command like "java - version"

Tags: jenkins

Find Jenkins version in CLI Command.

I can tell there are 3 ways to do it.

1. Open config file from the installation directory

   ```
   cd /var/lib/Jenkins/
   ```

   Open `config.xml` file, to see the version.
2. Available in bottom of Jenkins’s UI.
3. ```
   grep "version>" /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
   ```

This is the way!

```
 java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --version
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Is this related to programming in any way?

Comment: No.. This isn't about programming. Just to want to know.. Will appreciate it if could help on this. Thanks

Comment: **What** do you want to know? Please edit your question to contain a proper question

Comment: This is it. 

java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --version

Comment: @BalaSenthil Is the #3 the answer to your question?

Answer (score 4):

Locate `jenkins.war` [1] and run it with `java -jar` adding `--version` switch, thus:

```
    $ java -jar /path/to/jenkins/jenkins.war --version
```

where:

`path/to/jenkins` is your location of `jenkins.war`, which can be as follows (depending on your linux distro):

- `/usr/lib/jenkins`
- `/usr/share/jenkins`
- ..

---

[1] bonus - how to locate Jenkins JAR:

```
$ cd / && find | grep "jenkins/jenkins.war"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to get the current version of jenkins you can execute

```sh
jenkins --version
```

The `jenkins` executable in `/usr/bin` is a shell script that determines where the jenkins war is located, and then runs commands against it.

```sh
$ jenkins --help
Running from: /usr/share/java/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Jenkins Automation Server Engine 2.332.2
Usage: java -jar jenkins.war [--option=value] [--option=value]
...
a bunch of options to pass to the war file
```